# Excel VBA Centering contents in a Word Document table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, text-alignment

I am creating a macro in Excel that inserts a table in Word at a specific bookmark.  The table insertion process and the process that updates the table is working like I expect it to.

Now, I'm trying to align the data in the table.  I'm using the following code to align the data in the table cells:

```
objTbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
objTbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

This works great and is exactly how I want the data to appear.

The only issue I'm having is the data appears at the top of each cell and I would like it in the middle of each cell.  Is this possible?  I tried to adjust the row height with the following code:

```
WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Height = 15
```

I've tried both 15 and 20 and it didn't make a difference.
My VBA experience has been overwhelmingly within Excel.  So this is a bit of a learning curve to program Word from Excel.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help.......

Comment: Try something like:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should spend part of your 60 minutes of research in recording a macro. Whilst you wouldn't want to use the recorded code it will point you to the objects and properties you need to use. Of course you do need to know how to use the UI to achieve what you want first.

```
Sub CellAlignment()
'
' CellAligment Macro
'
'
   Selection.SelectCell
   Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
   Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
End Sub
```

Having recorded the code you can then use the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cells.verticalalignment) or the object explorer to get a pointer to more usable code, e.g.

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
```

Comment: @TimothyRylatt........Thanks for the advice.  I'll give it a try today........

Comment: @TimothyRylatt.........Thanks for the suggestion.  I recorded a macro and found that the issue was the spacing after.  I'm working on the syntax now.  I don't want to apply it to the whole document, just the table I'm creating.

Can I apply this to the whole table or do I have to go cell by cell?

Comment: @Shaves - For table formatting to work correctly the table needs to be inserted in a paragraph formatted with Normal style, and the definition of Normal style ***must*** match the document defaults. (These are set via the "Set Defaults" tab of the Manage Style dialog, and cannot be set via VBA) This will result in the space after being automatically suppressed in tables.

Comment: @Shaves - If the above is not the case in your document you will need to either: 1) set the space after to zero for the range where you will be creating the table; 2) loop through each cell of the table and apply the formatting.

Comment: @Shaves - This is just one of the many reasons why it is advisable to create your documents from a template (.dotx/.dotm) that already has the default formatting you require.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt............Thanks for the info.  I have a "standard" Word document (.docx) with specific verbiage I'm using as a "template".  This "template" has 2 bookmarks.  My macro opens an Excel file, and looks for specific data.  When it finds it, a web address is inserted at one bookmark (within one of the paragraphs) and then the table is added at the 2nd bookmark.  It cycles through the Excel file and creates a new document from the template with any new data.

Based on your reply, I'm going to look at the spacing in the template and set it there instead of with VBA.  Better solution

Comment: @TimothyRylatt...............My original thought was to cycle though each cell in the table and set it there but I haven't got that to work yet.  This is my last attempt:

objTbl.Cell(i, 3).Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

I'm sure you will quickly see what the issue is with this code.  I think I may have mentioned that I haven't done much VBA with Word so it's always an adventure.  I get there with research and help from other's, like youirself, willing to share their experience and knowledge.  Thanks again for all of your help......

Comment: @TimothyRylatt...........that was the answer.  I set the spacing on the "Template" and it did exactly what I was trying to do.  Thanks again for all of your help....